# Temporarily modifying the chapter headings' layout

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

I would like to modify the layout of some "special" chapters in my document, but afterwards reset to the layout I used before, i.e.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Normal Chapter}
\section{Normal Section}
\subsection{Normal Subsection}

% ask for current lay out:

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-40pt}{10pt}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\centering\Large\bf}{}{0pt}{}{}
\titleformat{\section}{\large\bf}{}{0pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalsize\it}{}{0pt}{}

\chapter{Special Chapter}
\section{Special Section}
\subsection{Special Subsection}

% reset to initial lay out

\chapter{Normal Chapter Again}
\section{Normal Section Again}
\subsection{Normal Subsection Again}

\end{document}
```

How can I define variables that store the current settings and subsequently use them to reset?

Comment: When I read the title I assumed you wanted to change the page geometry. Would you consider changing the title to include, 'chapter headings'?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can group to limit the scope:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Normal Chapter}
\section{Normal Section}
\subsection{Normal Subsection}

% ask for current lay out:

\begingroup
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-40pt}{10pt}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\centering\Large\bf}{}{0pt}{}{}
\titleformat{\section}{\large\bf}{}{0pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalsize\it}{}{0pt}{}

\chapter{Special Chapter}
\section{Special Section}
\subsection{Special Subsection}
\endgroup
% reset to initial lay out

\chapter{Normal Chapter Again}
\section{Normal Section Again}
\subsection{Normal Subsection Again}

\end{document}
```

You can aldo define a new command to store your new settings, and then use this command inside a group as before:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\newcommand\speciallayout{
  \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-40pt}{10pt}
  \titleformat{\chapter}{\centering\Large\bf}{}{0pt}{}{}
  \titleformat{\section}{\large\bf}{}{0pt}{}
  \titleformat{\subsection}{\normalsize\it}{}{0pt}{}
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Normal Chapter}
\section{Normal Section}
\subsection{Normal Subsection}

% ask for current lay out:

\begingroup
\speciallayout
\chapter{Special Chapter}
\section{Special Section}
\subsection{Special Subsection}
\endgroup
% reset to initial lay out

\chapter{Normal Chapter Again}
\section{Normal Section Again}
\subsection{Normal Subsection Again}

\end{document}
```

Defining a similar command for the standard layout, you can now switch styles using the two commands without having to explicitly group:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\newcommand\speciallayout{
  \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-40pt}{10pt}
  \titleformat{\chapter}{\centering\Large\bf}{}{0pt}{}{}
  \titleformat{\section}{\large\bf}{}{0pt}{}
  \titleformat{\subsection}{\normalsize\it}{}{0pt}{}
}
\newcommand\normallayout{
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{40pt}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Normal Chapter}
\section{Normal Section}
\subsection{Normal Subsection}

\speciallayout
\chapter{Special Chapter}
\section{Special Section}
\subsection{Special Subsection}

\normallayout
\chapter{Normal Chapter Again}
\section{Normal Section Again}
\subsection{Normal Subsection Again}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Good that you provided three alternatives. But, wondering if in your second example it be better to define an environment `speciallayout` so that you don't accidentally use it without enclosing it within a group?